# For loop to parse files with spaces in path, Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, xmlstarlet

Have a Windows command prompt line:

```
for /F %i in ('dir /s /b D:\MyDirectory\filepath\File.xml') do (C:\progra~1\xmlstarlet\xml.exe ed --inplace -d "//xmlTag[data/url[contains(text(),'shop.companyname')]]" %i)
```

One of the more than 100 directories has a space in the path, and this line fails on that directory. Names must be preserved.

Tried changing `delims` option to `^n`, but that failed on more than one directory.

Also tried `%~dp0`but don't understand the syntax, and `"%~dp0\File.xml"`, which gives me "cannot find the file specified".

How do I get Windows to parse that line with the space? Is there a `delims=[not space?]` option?

Comment: Would rather not search and replace the space, unless that's the only way.

Answer (score 4):

To scan folder with `dir` in `for loop`, you have to use `"delims="` because the default `delims` is `space`.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b "D:\MyDirectory\filepath\*.xml"') do @( echo "%~i" )
```

I updated the sample, `%i` are now in double quotes. Thus your external software will see as a single argument

As stated @aschipfl, you can change to `"%~i"`. see `call /?` or `for /?` - sample updated

Comment: same failure to load entity. :(

Comment: same result for `for /F "delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b "D:\MyDirectory\filepath\File.xml"') do (C:\progra~1\xmlstarlet\xml.exe ed --inplace -d "//xmlTag[data/url[contains(text(),'shop.companyname')]]" %i)`.

Comment: @motorbaby: Around "%i" I'd say

Comment: Message was "failure to load external entity". Solution below worked with tokens instead of delims and `"%i %j"`.

Comment: After `do`, use the `for` variable like `"%~i"` -- the `~` removes any surrounding quotes from the value, then quotes are explicitely surrounded, so the result is *always* a value within quotes; so the command receiving that value does no longer treat it as multiple arguments in case of spaces in the value...

Comment: Yes, this also works: `for /F "delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b "D:\MyDirectory\filepath\File.xml"') do (C:\progra~1\xmlstarlet\xml.exe ed --inplace -d "//xmlTag[data/url[contains(text(),'shop.companyname')]]" "%i")`. THANKS, GUYS! `"%~i"` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `delims=` there is also `tokens=` that you can use to limit the number of tokens returned. Try setting it to `1,*`. This will give you `%i` for everything before the first space and `%j` for everything behind the first space.

Then, in the `do` part, combine `%i %j`.

Example:

```
for /F "tokens=1,*" %i in ('set') DO @echo %i %j
```

Comment: Still get failed to load external entity for the one file. Used `for /F "tokens=1,*" %i in ('dir /s /b D:\MyDirectory\filepath\File.xml') do (C:\progra~1\xmlstarlet\xml.exe ed --inplace -d "//xmlTag[data/url[contains(text(),'shop.companyname')]]" %i %j)`

Comment: @motorbaby: In your case, put quotes around "%i %j" since it must probably be a single argument to xml.exe

Comment: IT WORKED! THANKS @Thomas!!!! [thumbsup] Solution: `for /F "tokens=1,*" %i in ('dir /s /b D:\MyDirectory\filepath\File.xml') do (C:\progra~1\xmlstarlet\xml.exe ed --inplace -d "//xmlTag[data/url[contains(text(),'shop.companyname')]]" "%i %j")`

Comment: @motorbaby: Please try Paul's solution with `"%i"` in the `do` part. If that works, it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is to tell FOR that the entire line, spaces and all, go into the %i variable.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`DIR /S /B *.xml`) do (ECHO "%~i")
```